# Problem with finding successive integers in C

Tags: c

The main problem of the code is that finally the programm shows every time that there are not successive integers.

At first, I tried to figure out a solution to this problem, by investigating how to correct the "if" statement and then to fix some small mistakes on the code, but I was unable to find any error. The code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    int a,i;
    int A[10];
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        A[i]=a;
    }
    if ((A[i+1]-A[i]==1)||(A[i+1]-A[i]==-1)) {
        printf("{%d,%d}",A[i+1],A[i]);
    } else {
        printf("Den yparxoun diadoxikoi arithmoi");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Well, the expected result is to show, if exist, the successive integers as pairs. For example if I write the integers 4,-1,9,8,3,5,-21,6,7,8 the program should print {9,8}{6,7}{7,8}. The actual result is to show every time that there are not successive integers.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Because, you do it outside a loop, so you test only one possibility (the last). But your `i` is at 9 so 9+1, on a array of size 10 is undifined

Comment: In the first `if`, what is the value of `i+1`? I think you have undefined behavior.

Comment: When you do the check, `i` contains `10` and you access the array out of bounds. You should check for each i from 1..8, not only for one value

Comment: Your 'if' condition should be in a 'for' loop to check for all iterations of 'i'. Also you want to find if the modulus of the subtraction should be equal to 1.

Comment: "The actual result is to show every time that there are not successive integers."  Eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to use a loop in order to find out the pair by adding the loop your code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int a,i,flag=0;
    int A[10];

    for(i=0; i<=9; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        A[i]=a;
    }

    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        if ((A[i+1]-A[i]==1)||(A[i+1]-A[i]==-1)) 
        {
            printf("{%d,%d}",A[i+1],A[i]);
            flag=1;
        } 
    }

    if(!flag)
        printf("Den yparxoun diadoxikoi arithmoi");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in the 'compare loop' you compare `A[i]` with `A[i+1]` what doesn't match `for(i=1;i<10;i++)`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt can you explain what do you want to point in a clearer way?

Comment: well, you never compare `A[0]` with `A[1]` and vou access `A[10]` what causes Undefined Behaviour

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt oh thanks!! I forgot that I'll do the edit

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You helped a lot

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

int a,i;
int A[10];
int c =0;
for(i=0; i<=9; i++) {
    scanf("%d",&a);
    A[i]=a;
}
for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
{
if(A[i+1]==10)
{
break;
}

else if ((A[i+1]-A[i]==1)||(A[i+1]-A[i]==-1)) 
{
    printf("{%d,%d}",A[i],A[i+1]);
    c=1;
} 
}

if(!c)

    printf("Den yparxoun diadoxikoi arithmoi");



return 0;
```

}

Comment: check for the bounds of the second `for` loop, please

Comment: I didn't know if he wants to print the 'else' for every incorrect sequence or at the end. @IngoLeonhardt

Comment: That's not what i meant; you have `i <= 9` and `A[i+1]`

Comment: Don't you want to fix that? accessing `A[10]` causes Undefined Behaviour

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The only problem is that the programm prints "Den yparxoun diadoxikoi arithmoi" ("There are not successive integers" in greek with latin characters) every time two integers, if they are not successive

Comment: I made the change. Thanks @IngoLeonhardt

Comment: still not correct: with `if(A[i+1]==10)` you still access `A[10]`, nothing gained. Just change the loop to `for(i=0; i<9; i++) { .. }` (or `i<=8` if you prefer that)